How can I convert a number stored as string to binary?
I'm using Rust Polars, and want to convert from a number stored as a string to a binary representation of the value as a binary column. This is so I can do some comparisons on IPv6 numbers, which are too big to store in the Polars Decimal type.
Has anyone got any examples of how to do this? Or even working with binary data in Polars?
I'm able to use a mapping function to convert to a u128 type, and from that into bytes - but I'm not sure how to get that back into a Polars series.

Can you post an example of the exact input and output you're expecting?

So for an input of "42", it would convert to the number 42 as u128. That bit's easy enough, but how do I get that into a binary series in Polars?

Polars is basically a SQL query engine and is almost as difficult to extend. I think the way you're meant to do this is by writing an expression plugin.
Alternatively, you might be able to transform your data outside of Polars, save the result to a new file, then feed Polars that.
However, after much wrangling I was able to get the hack below to work. Comments in the code explain.
use polars::prelude::*;

/// Custom conversion function to apply to every string.
///
/// This returns 16-byte little-endian binary values, and treats parse errors as null.
/// Likely you'll want different details, but since this is just regular Rust code it
/// should be easy to implement!
fn convert_value(s: &str) -> Option<Vec<u8>> {
    s.parse::<u128>().ok().map(|u| u.to_le_bytes().to_vec())
}

/// Converts a whole series of string data to binary.
fn convert_series(series: Series) -> Result<Option<Series>, PolarsError> {
    let data: Vec<Option<Vec<u8>>> = series
        .str()
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        .map(|s| s.and_then(convert_value))
        .collect();
    Ok(Some(Series::new("name", data)))
}

/// Tells Polars what type of result the custom conversion function will produce. (Polars doesn't
/// want to just call the function and see. It needs to know this type in advance.)
///
/// Note: Context is not directly exposed in the `polars` crate API, so use a type parameter...
fn field_type<Context>(_schema: &Schema, _context: Context, _fields: &[Field]) -> Field {
    Field::new("name", DataType::Binary)
}

fn main() {
    let df = df! (
        "nums" => &["123", "416", "32491846598726498275", "", "N/A"],
    )
    .unwrap();

    let out = df
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .select([col("nums")
            // Use Expr::map to apply the conversion.
            .map(convert_series, SpecialEq::new(Arc::new(field_type)))
            .alias("binary")])
        .collect()
        .unwrap();

    println!("{out}");
}

The output is:
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────────────────────────────────┐
│ binary                          │
│ ---                             │
│ binary                          │
╞═════════════════════════════════╡
│ b"{\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0… │
│ b"\xa0\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00… │
│ b"\xe3\xb7\x93\x15U:\xea\xc2\x… │
│ null                            │
│ null                            │
└─────────────────────────────────┘

Expr::map is not the easiest API to use. It must be on purpose, to try and get users to gravitate toward the built-in functions, which Polars knows how to optimize.
